# Why is the 'simplified' code not vectorized

Tags: c++, gcc, rust, clang, vectorization

I implemented the following code which converts 32 bytes of input to uppercase:

Version 1:

```
void to_upper(char* input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) { 
        input[i] = (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z') ? input[i] - 32 : input[i]; 
    }
}
```

Version 2:

```
void to_upper(char* input) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; ++i) { 
        if (input[i] >= 'a' && input[i] <= 'z') {
            input[i] = input[i] - 32; // same for: input[i] -= 32;
        }
    }
}
```

The first version gets autovectorized, the second doesn't. The behaviour is consistent across clang and gcc. Moreover, I implemented both versions in Rust, too, and the Rust compiler does the same, Version 1 autovectorized, Version 2 isn't.

What is limiting the compiler from vectorizing the second version?

Comment: The second version is problematic due to the conditional assignment. A compiler is not allowed to invent assignments.

Comment: @rustyx Sounds reasonable but I have 2 problems with this explanation.

1) With all the transformations that the compiler is doing, a trivial assignment like `input[i] = input[i]` should be allowed.
2) Even if I add an else branch in Version 2, where I simply call `else { input[i] = input[i]; }`, vectorization still doesn't happen.

Comment: Version 1 is effectively branchless when compiled to assembly, the compiler should apply conditional moves whereas the second requires conditional branching and jumps.

Comment: What flags did you use? Did you try it with `-O3`?

Comment: @DavidFrank From this example: https://godbolt.org/z/bzzE7a it seems that adding a `input[i] = input[i]` is optimised out, still resulting in a conditional jump. The jump is probably the reason why it isn't vectorised.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically optimization passes have harder time recognizing the conditional assignment in second loop.

In first case GCC generates a slightly different intermediate representation which allows if-conversion pass to convert code to vectorizable form:

```
  <bb 3>:
  # i_18 = PHI <i_14(4), 0(2)>
  # ivtmp_24 = PHI <ivtmp_21(4), 32(2)>
  _6 = (sizetype) i_18;
  _7 = input_5(D) + _6;
  _8 = *_7;
  _9 = (unsigned char) _8;
  _10 = _9 + 159;
  _11 = _9 + 224;
  iftmp.0_12 = (char) _11;
  iftmp.0_2 = _10 <= 25 ? iftmp.0_12 : _8;
  *_7 = iftmp.0_2;
  i_14 = i_18 + 1;
  ivtmp_21 = ivtmp_24 - 1;
  if (ivtmp_21 != 0)
    goto <bb 4>;
  else
    goto <bb 5>;
```

whereas in second case code contains spurious jumps which complicate analysis and break vectorization:

```
  <bb 3>:
  # i_15 = PHI <i_14(6), 0(2)>
  # ivtmp_26 = PHI <ivtmp_25(6), 32(2)>
  _5 = (sizetype) i_15;
  _7 = input_6(D) + _5;
  _8 = *_7;
  _9 = (unsigned char) _8;
  _10 = _9 + 159;
  if (_10 <= 25)
    goto <bb 4>;
  else
    goto <bb 5>;

  <bb 4>:
  _11 = _9 + 224;
  _12 = (char) _11;
  *_7 = _12;

  <bb 5>:
  i_14 = i_15 + 1;
  ivtmp_25 = ivtmp_26 - 1;
  if (ivtmp_25 != 0)
    goto <bb 6>;
  else
    goto <bb 7>;
```

Many optimization passes work as pattern matchers which recognize and optimize common cases so I wouldn't be surprised with this behavior.

You can try filing a bug in [GCC tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/).